# Создать массив из возвращаемых функцией значений

Tags: lua

Есть некая функция, она возвращает много значений. Всегда можно взять, например, третье значение с помощью `_,_,A=func()`. Но проблема в том, что эта функция возвращает всегда разное кол-во значений. Мне нужно отправить все полученные от функции значения в массив. На конкретном примере было выяснено, что при некоторых обстоятельствах функция всегда возвращает 7 значений. Однако, в случае `arr=func()` в  arr оказалось 57 значений. Из этого я делаю вывод, что необходимо при первом вызове функции в цикле добавить каждое значение в массив. Что-то вроде `for i,val in func() do arr[#arr+1]=val end`, где val -- это i-тое возвращаемое значение функции.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Массивы в lua реализованы как таблицы.

Можно присвоить сразу все возвращенные значения следующим образом:

```
arr = { func() }
```

То есть добавить фигурные скобки.

Comment: Скажите, пожалуйста, как можно сразу обратиться к конкретному аргументу? Допустим, функция возвращает несколько элементов, я их отправляю в таблицу с помощью приведённого примера. arr = {func()}. Дальше чтобы обратиться к некоторому элементу я использую arr[index]. Можно ли как-то сразу обратиться к определённому индексу? {func()}[index] не работает. upd: уже нашёл ответ. rawget({func()},index)